# items not appearing when running the code

Tags: list, prompt, items

`
"Disc Arena": {"items": ["Light Disc"], "north": "Light Cycle Garage", "east": "Power Grid", "south": None, "west": "Control Room"},
"Light Cycle Garage": {"items": ["Light Cycle"], "north": None, "east": "Recognizer Platform", "south": "Disc Arena", "west": None},
"Power Grid": {"items": ["Power Cell"], "north": "Recognizer Platform", "south": None, "west": "Disc Arena", "east": None},
"Control Room": {"items": ["Control Panel"], "north": None, "east": "Disc Arena", "south": None, "west": None},
"Recognizer Platform": {"items": ["Recognizer Scanner"],"north": None, "East": None, "South": "Power Grid", "west": "Light Cycle Garage"},

}

## Main game loop

while True:
# Print the current room name and items
print("You are in the", current_room)
print("You see the following items:", rooms[current_room]["items"])

```
# Check if all 6 items have been collected
if len(items) == 6:
    print("You have collected all the items! You are the champion of the Grid!")
    break
```

`
when i run it items only shows []